# Cassandra data model for user login : partition and clustering key confusion

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I want user to login using email id or mobile no. or userName.
I am new to cassandra can anyone suggest me the right data model.

I am thinking in this way...

Table - user

- userName //treat it as userId PK
- emailId
- mobile No
- password

or  should I create 3 tables

-userName 
-password

-emailId
-password

-mobileNo
-password

also how can I benefit from cassandra partition and clustering key concept?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Create three tables –

```
Create table User_by_userid{
 username text,
 email text,
 mobileno text,
 password
 primary key (username)

 }

   Create table User_by_email{
    username text,
    email text,
    mobileno text,
    password
    primary key (email)

 }

  Create table User_by_mobileno{
    username text,
    email text,
    mobileno text,
    password
    primary key (mobileno)

  }
```

This will be the efficient way.  Data copy is very helpful while Cassandra data modelling. Cassandra is write intensive database. Writes are very cheap. 
You need to have application level lock on while creating the user, you need to check if the user exist by the email/uname/mobile no. This is the check-then-act case.